# Block javascript execution and wait on event triggered in UI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a method in which I want to stop execution (do not return), wait on an event triggered by the UI, then continue that method.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {

        var newHeaders;
        //I need to stop here, wait on some user event, update the `newHeaders` variable with
        //the content set by the user on the page

        return {requestHeaders:newHeaders};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

What I'm doing: Developing a chrome plugin that [intercepts requests](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders), modify them by the input of the user from html, then send the request. Based on the docs, I assumed I have to modify it directly in the method and return it.

Comment: JavaScript itself has no facility to stop execution. Why not just drop out of the function and wait for the event to trigger another function call?

Comment: @Diodeus Actually, it has some blocking functions such as `alert` or `prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this points you in the right direction:

The docs at: http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/webRequest.html say:

> If the optional opt_extraInfoSpec array contains the string 'blocking'
>   (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled
>   synchronously. That means that the request is blocked until the
>   callback function returns. In this case, the callback can return a
>   BlockingResponse that determines the further life cycle of the
>   request. Depending on the context, this response allows cancelling or
>   redirecting a request (onBeforeRequest), cancelling a request or
>   modifying headers (onBeforeSendHeaders, onHeadersReceived), or
>   providing authentication credentials (onAuthRequired).

My guess is that you can specify "blocking" and then gather information from your user.

Comment: Thank you, I read that too, but don't quite understand how to implement it as the code samples given are limited in regards to that feature